# Sumar filas de una columna Html Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Tengo una tabla con datos obtenidos desde `Python`, lo renderizo a `HTML` con `Jinja2`.

La tabla es la siguiente

```
<table class="table table-sm  table-striped w-100" id="ejemplo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Empleador</th>
                        <th>Mes Liquidado</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Liquidación</th>
                        <th>Cantidad de Empleados</th>
                        <th>Importe</th>
                        <th>Cuota Sindical</th>
                        <th>Res. 11/16</th>
                        <th>Otros Aportes</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {%for datos in datos%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{datos.15}}</td>
                        <td>{{datos.4.strftime('%m-%Y')}}</td>
                        <td>{{datos.5.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}</td>
                        <td>{{datos.9}}</td>
                        <td id="Total0">{{"${:,.2f}".format(datos.6)}}</td>
                        <td id="Total1">{{"${:,.2f}".format(datos.6*15/1000)}}</td>
                        <td id="Total2">{{"${:,.2f}".format(datos.6*15/1000)}}</td>
                        <td id="Total3">{{"${:,.2f}".format(datos.8)}}</td>
                        <td id="Total4">{{"${:,.2f}".format(datos.8+datos.6*15/1000+datos.6*15/1000)}}</td>
                        {%if datos.10==1%}<td>Anulada</td>{%endif%}
                        {%if datos.10==0%}<td>Generada</td>{%endif%}
                        {%if datos.10==2%}<td>Pendiente</td>{%endif%}
                        {%if datos.10==3%}<td>Confirmada</td>{%endif%}
                    </tr>
                    {%endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

El caso es que quiero sumar las las cada fila de las `<td>` que poseen por `id="TotalN"`.

Vi códigos en `Javascript` pero ninguno me ha funcionado, como puedo hacerlo de tal forma que al `<tfooter>` pueda aplicar los resultados obtenidos en la función. La función es llamada junto con la carga de la página.

Comment: ¿Qué valores tienen almacenados esas celdas?

Comment: datos.6 ? eso si quiera es valido?

Comment: Son `decimal` que por medio de la  función `{{"${:,.2f}".format()}}`  se convierten en price

Comment: pero osea, datos no es una variable entonces?, porque si es asi tendria que tener una propiedad 6, no se, muy raro. se supone no puedes ponerle puntos decimales de esa forma.

Comment: @Riven, si son validos, son decimales obtenidos de una tabla Mysql desde Flask, el caso es que no lo puedo hacer desde la funcion SUM() de SQL porque el resto son datos calculables. Se envian como parametro a Jinja2 con el nombre de datos, si bien no es una buena practica, es lo que se establecio previamente

Comment: Entonces quieres sumar el valor de 5 celdas?

Comment: Hola @MatiasLucero, ¿puedes colocar un ejemplo de código HTML renderizados con valores de ejemplo? El objetivo es copiar todo el código HTML y programarlo para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Solo recorre el `tbody tr` con un `each`, y almacena los valores en variables como `t0, t1, ...,t4`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    sumarTbody();
});

function sumarTbody(){
    var t0=0,t1=0,t2=0,t3=0,t4=0;
    $("#datosasumar tr").each(function(ind,ele){//recorre tr's
        $("td",ele).each(function(i,e){//recorre td's            
          if(i==4) t0+=parseFloat($(e).html());
          if(i==5) t1+=Number($(e).html());
          if(i==6) t2+=Number($(e).html());
          if(i==7) t3+=Number($(e).html());
          if(i==8) t4+=Number($(e).html());
        })
    })
    console.log(t0,t1,t2,t3,t4);//renderiza tu footer con estos valores
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm  table-striped w-100" id="ejemplo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Empleador</th>
            <th>Mes Liquidado</th>
            <th>Fecha de Liquidación</th>
            <th>Cantidad de Empleados</th>
            <th>Importe</th>
            <th>Cuota Sindical</th>
            <th>Res. 11/16</th>
            <th>Otros Aportes</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="datosasumar">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>01-10-2020</td>
            <td>02-10-2020</td>
            <td>dato1</td>
            <td>33.41</td>
            <td>65.33</td>
            <td>32.21</td>
            <td>34.32</td>
            <td>100.22</td>
            <td>Confirmada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>03-10-2020</td>
            <td>04-10-2020</td>
            <td>dato1</td>
            <td>33.41</td>
            <td>65.33</td>
            <td>32.21</td>
            <td>34.32</td>
            <td>100.22</td>
            <td>Confirmada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>05-10-2020</td>
            <td>06-10-2020</td>
            <td>dato3</td>
            <td>33.41</td>
            <td>65.33</td>
            <td>32.21</td>
            <td>34.32</td>
            <td>100.22</td>
            <td>Confirmada</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo único que faltaría es renderizar tu `footer`.